# C++ compacting an array according to a qualification predicate

Tags: c++, stl

The goal of this question is to seek for a better/best way to implement the required function.  As I am only familiar with part of the C++ STL, the described function may be already been some form/pattern/algorithm in C++ STL.  A better design/implementation or pointing me a good STL function handling this will be welcome.

Now the question...

Suppose I have an array of type `foo`, and a predicate function `pred`, say,

```
foo bar[100];
bool pred(const foo *p);
```

I want to compact the array by applying the predicate `pred` as a qualification function: unqualified items (i.e. when `pred` returns false) will be removed from the array, and all elements after that should be moved forward.

My first thought would be to write a more general template, so that this operation can be done on all types:

```
template <typename IteratorType>
IteratorType CompactAnArray(IteratorType first, IteratorType last, bool (*pred)(IteratorType));
```

This function should do the described job, in the range of [first .. last), using the predication function `pred`.  The return value should be the ending iterator of the newly formed 'Array'.  In case I need to know the size of the new array, I can use `std::distance()` to calculate the distance between my array (say, `bar`) and the return value of the template function.

I do have an easy implementation for this template function in about 30 lines.  However, I wonder if C++ STL already has a solution.

Comment: Ouch... it needs C++17 and up.    I only have C++11.   Sigh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

> Removes all elements satisfying specific criteria from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new end of the range.
>
> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged.

Comment: @RobinHsu Nah, `std::remove_if` is from `C++98`.

Comment: You are right.  The "until" part is OK to use.  Thanks.